# maps.API.Geocode - 'You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out'

Tags: salesforce, future, apex, callouts

I have problem using maps.API.Geocode in salesforce. The idea is to run a method via 'Process Builder', getting the longitude and latitude for a list of addresses. I assume that the callout may take a while, so I think I should use the `@future (callout = true)` annotation. When I run the 'poc' getGeocode() method:

```
public class GeocodeService {

    @InvocableMethod
    public static void getGeocode() {
        geocode();
    }
        
    public static void geocode() {
        Map <String, String> options = new Map <String, String> {'version' => '1', 'address' => '415 Mission Street, San Francisco, CA 94105 USA'};
        Map<String, object> result;
        result = (Map<String, object>) maps.API.Geocode(options);
        System.debug(result);        
    }
}
```

Everything works as it should. But when I add `@future (callout = true)` to geocode() method and run it again, I get this message

```
| FATAL_ERROR | System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out
```

I run the method from the console, I don't do any DML before, where should I look for the cause of the problem?